# Not sure why variable's name is not correct, object won't remove from stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

[image]   Trying to go to the next page when a listing is clicked, but i think the name of object at the moment is not correct. I am not very sure on why the listing on stage won't be removed, i added it on a if statement.If i click it, it doesnt do anything, and if i do removeChild(newListing) then it gives me an error of access of undefined property, so i think because thats not the properties name. If i remove everything off the stage using

```
if(stage.numChildren > 0)
{
  stage.removeChildAt(0);
}
```

then it disappear, but it doesn't add the next Child.

```
package com.clark

{
import com.clark.VectorTest;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.text.TextField;
import com.clark.TouchScroller;
    import com.clark.Viewport;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import fl.controls.Button;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

       public class Autoresult extends MovieClip {

        public var s1:Autoresult2 = new Autoresult2 ();
public var s3:VectorTest= new VectorTest(new Vector.<Auto>);



               public function Autoresult()
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onadded);
         function onadded (event:Event):void{

            addChild(s1);
         }



             s1.ARhome.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,home);
            s1.ARauto.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, auto);
             s1.ARsearch.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,searchss);

if( s3.lists.length > 0 )
        {
            // get the first listing in the listing array
            var newListing:Listing9 = s3.lists[0];
            newListing.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoscener);
        }



       }
            private function home (event:MouseEvent):void{
         var s5:Account = new Account ();   
    removeChild(s1);
    removeChild(newListing);

            addChild(s5);

            }
            private function auto (event:MouseEvent):void{
         var s4:Auto = new Auto (); 
    removeChild(s1);
            addChild(s4);

            }
}
}
```

VectorTest.as

```
package  com.clark
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    public class VectorTest extends MovieClip 
    {
          public var lists:Vector.<Listing9>;


        public function VectorTest(tests:Vector.<Auto>) 
        {

            for (var j:int = 0; j < tests.length; j++) 

            {

                trace(tests[j].nobed);
                trace(tests[j].zip);
                trace(tests[j].rangelow);
                trace(tests[j].rangehigh);





        }

            var ben:int = tests ? tests.length : 0;

         lists = new Vector.<Listing9>(ben, true);
            var currentYs:int = 120;

            for (var k:int = 0; k < tests.length; k++) 
            {
                var Bolder:Listing9 = new Listing9();


                Bolder.x=40;



                var tf:TextField = new TextField();
                var tf1:TextField = new TextField();
                var tf2:TextField = new TextField();
                var tf3:TextField = new TextField();

                tf3.width = 100;
                tf.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat("Arial", 12, 0, null, null, null, null, null, TextFormatAlign.CENTER);

                tf.width = 100;
                tf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                tf1.width = 100;
                tf1.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                tf2.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                tf3.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                tf3.width = 100;
                tf1.y= tf.height+5;



                tf.text = tests[k].nobed;
                tf1.text = tests[k].zip;
                tf2.text = tests[k].rangelow;
                tf3.text = tests[k].rangehigh;


                tf.x = (Bolder.height-tf.height)*.2

                Bolder.addChild(tf);
                Bolder.addChild(tf1);
                Bolder.addChild(tf2);
                Bolder.addChild(tf3);


                    // position the object based on the accumulating variable.
                Bolder.y = currentYs;



                addChild(Bolder);
                Bolder.mouseChildren = false;    // ignore children mouseEvents
                Bolder.mouseEnabled = true;      // enable mouse on the object - normally set to true by default
                Bolder.useHandCursor = true;     // add hand cursor on mouse over
                Bolder.buttonMode = true; 
                 lists[k] = Bolder;
                currentYs += Bolder.height + 10;
            }
        if( lists.length > 0 )
        {

            lists[0].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gotoscener);
            lists[1].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gotoscener1);
            lists[2].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gotoscener2);
        }

        }
        private function gotoscener(event:MouseEvent):void{

            var s9:Autodetail = new Autodetail ();  


            addChild(s9);


       }
       private function gotoscener1(event:MouseEvent):void{

            var s9:Autodetail = new Autodetail ();  


            addChild(s9);


       }
       private function gotoscener2(event:MouseEvent):void{

            var s9:Autodetail = new Autodetail ();  


            addChild(s9);


       }
    }

}
```

Comment: You are asking about stage, but in `Autoresult` listing nothing about it. Also you remove `newListing` from the display list, but I can't see any code about adding it.

Comment: I just spent sometime on it, and realized because the listing was actually added in VectorTest.as which i edit and attached above. But the other parts is added in the Autoresult as, such as the background and buttons. I believe i have to pass the instance through from VectorTest to Autoresult? i am having trouble passing it through at the moment. Not sure if you can give me some hint on how to pass it through successfully. THanks

Comment: Again, what problem do you have exactly? Do you want create UI components in the VectorTest and path result to the AutoResult?

Comment: At the moment the list is created from the VectorTest and background and button are added from Autoresult, what i want to do is when the list is clicked from Vector Test, the background,button everything is removed, and i add a new child. But the problem at the moment is,when i click the list from VectorTest, i can't remove the background etc added from Autoresult.

Comment: I attached an image, when i click the orange list(that is added from VectorTest) it doesn't remove everything from stage(the background, buttons etc). I need to go to the next "page" when a list is clicked,but it doesn't at the moment

Answer (score 0):

If you want manage display list, create some containers, that will help you in this task. For example, create container for the overlay UI elements, and for the content;

```
public var s1:Autoresult2 = new Autoresult2 ();
public var s3:VectorTest= new VectorTest(new Vector.<Auto>);
private var _overlay: Sprite;
private var _contentHolder: Sprite;
```

Create containers and add them to the display list:

```
function onadded (e:Event):void{
    _contentHolder = new Sprite();
    _overlay = new Sprite();        

    addChild(_contenHolder);
    addChild(_overlay);
    _overlay.addChild(s1);
    //If you want to hide overlay, you could set _overlay.visible = false, or remove children from the _overlay

    //Your code with buttons from s1

    if( s3.lists.length > 0 ){
        // get the first listing in the listing array
        var newListing:Listing9 = s3.lists[0];
        newListing.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoscene);
        _contentHolder.addChild(newListing);
    }
}
```

Now, when user clicks `newListing` you can decide how to manage display list:

```
function gotoscene(e: MouseEvent):void{
    //Manage children of _contentHolder and _overlay
    //Remove everything from the _contentHolder, and add new content

    //In this example, everything will be remove from the _contentHolder
    //Will be added new content to the _contentHolder
    //overlay will be hidden for this operation
    while(_contentHolder.numChildren){
        _contentHolder.removeChildAt(0); 
    }

    _contentHolder.addChild(new Autodetail());
    _overlay.visible = false;
}
```

Comment: I am just wondering in the line where i put var newListing:Listing9 = s3.lists[0]; how would i make it so that it is not just the first listing box, but whatever box the user click?

Comment: Calculate box index, and use it with lists: `var newListing:Listing9 = s3.lists[boxIndex];`

Comment: I finally managed to do it after kept trying for days....i finally setup a global class and call it thru the global variable and i can click and remove child between the 2 class. But now gotta figure out how to session the data that was clicked.